# How do I find the creation date of a user in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, security

How do I find the creation date of a user in MongoDB?  As background, I'm used to doing this in relational databases like Oracle or MSSQL.

I've checked the admin.system.users table, as I thought I might be able to decode the `_id` in case it were a generated `ObjectID`, but no luck there, as it uses the {db}.{username} as the `_id`.

I could probably stuff the current timestamp into the `customData` field at user creation, but that would not be as reliable as the data dictionary queries I'm used to from the RDBMS cousins.  I would need to make sure all other DBAs follow the practice (not too hard, but prone to human error), but also make sure any 3rd party tools that do user administration (IDM) functionality follow suit (not easy).

Answer (score 2):

As at MongoDB 3.2, you are correct that the `admin.system.users` collection does not maintain metadata such as created or modified timestamps.

You can add metadata manually using `customData`, but as you noted this requires coordination with any applications or tools that are allowed to create users in your MongoDB deployment:

```
use admin
db.createUser({
     user: "bobbytables",
     pwd: "CorrectHorseBatteryStaple",
     customData: { created: new Date() },
     roles: [
        { role: "readWrite", db: "accounts" }
     ]
  })
```

Ideally this sort of metadata would be maintained by the database server in a standard format that tools could also choose to interpret. There is a relevant open feature request that you can watch/upvote: [SERVER-10021: Add timestamps to user documents](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-10021).

If you are using MongoDB Enterprise there are a few extra features that may help you with a workaround in the interim:

- You can use an [external authentication mechanism](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/authentication-mechanisms-enterprise/) that maintains metadata for users, such as Kerberos or LDAP.
- You could potentially [enable auditing](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/audit-message/#audit-event-actions-details-and-results) to capture `createUser` and `updateUser` events, and write an admin script to update the `customData` accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for the clear and well researched answer. Love the xkcd http://xkcd.com/ reference.